# be split up into/split into

Tags: verbs

In the sentences below, which usage is correct:

> All participants are split up into groups of 10.
>   All participants are split into groups of 10.

So, the participants are divided but the verb "split" has nothing to do here with the divorce or breaking up, rather dividing into different groups that will compete against each other.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/36656/386289)

Comment: I think "up" is unnecessary.

Comment: Does "all" seem awkward here to anyone else? I feel like "the" would be a better fit.

Comment: They are both grammatical.

Comment: Maybe “assigned to” would be a better way of saying it.

Comment: "All participants are split" makes it sound like *each* participant is split.  I would say "participants are split..." or "the participants are split...."  Up is optional.  I would omit it because I prefer to omit unnecessary prepositions. (Why print out the document when you can print the document?  Why split up the participants when you can split the participants?)

Comment: Thanks everybody!